# How to split a string in sql server 2008 using stored procedure and insert the data to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

I want to split a string in this format
Quote:

```
"date=10/10/2000|age=13^date=01/01/2001|age=12^date=02/02/2005|age=8"
```

.
Actually this string is only a sample one my original string is very large . i am not getting a point that if i break this string than how many variables i have to make to capture the data also after splitting the string i want that to be inserted into data table containing columns as date and age? What concept do i use?(I am getting this string from a web service) Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just a suggestion - capture string on web / controller , write a parser for you data i.e one object with date, age or other properties you have, create a collection of this objects and use bulk insert to db.

Comment: Also the string comes from a web service - is there any way to format as a JSon objects - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Comment: hey lets keep it pretty simple there is no need of JSON a far as i think...

Comment: sure - depends on your access to web service and feature requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I'd suggest to write a CLR function which split strings by regex or SQL table-valued function, but in you case you can try something simple like converting your string to xml and parsing it:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'date=10/10/2000|age=13^date=01/01/2001|age=12^date=02/02/2005|age=8'
declare @data xml

select @str = replace(@str, '=', '="')
select @str = replace(@str, '|', '" ')
select @str = replace(@str, '^', '"/><row ')
select @str = '<row ' + @str + '"/>'

select @data = cast(@str as xml)

select
    t.c.value('@date', 'nvarchar(max)') as [date],
    t.c.value('@age', 'nvarchar(max)') as [age]
from @data.nodes('row') as t(c)
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19337)

Comment: hi but it is giving error as "MSG 9410, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
XML parsing: line 1, character 20964, white space expected".

Comment: could you provide string so i can test it?

Comment: i am not able to post it to u...very large way beyond the capacity of comment box...i am telling you a thing that the string contains 25000 characters..

Comment: can you split your string by chunks and see where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Declare @stringToSplit varchar(max)='date=10/10/2000|age=13^date=01/01/2001|age=12^date=02/02/2005|age=8^date=10/10/2000|age=13^date=01/01/2001|age=12^date=02/02/2005|age=8^date=10/10/2000|age=13^date=01/01/2001|age=12^date=02/02/2005|age=8^date=10/10/2000|age=13^date=01/01/2001|age=12^date=02/02/2005|age=8'

DECLARE @YourTable table (RowID int, Layout varchar(max))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1,@stringToSplit)

;WITH SplitSting AS
(
    SELECT
    RowID,LEFT(Layout,CHARINDEX('^',Layout)-1) AS Part
   ,RIGHT(Layout,LEN(Layout)-CHARINDEX('^',Layout)) AS Remainder
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE Layout IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX('^',Layout)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    RowID,LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX('^',Remainder)-1)
   ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX('^',Remainder))
    FROM SplitSting
    WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX('^',Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    RowID,Remainder,null
    FROM SplitSting
    WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX('^',Remainder)=0

)

select SUBSTRING(part,CHARINDEX('=',part)+1,(CHARINDEX('|',part)-CHARINDEX('=',part))-1) as [Date],RIGHT(part,CHARINDEX('=',reverse(part))-1) as [Age] from SplitSting
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(300)
SET @s = 'RELGENINS|1121232243434|343434343434|343434-683211|34343434.00|CIT|22297568|NA|INR|ONDIRECT|NA|NA|NA|22-03-2014 10:43:20|0300|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|Success|1790153891'

DECLARE @tmp TABLE(   aDate varchar(50))

;WITH MyRows AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(@s, CHARINDEX('|', @s) -1) AS MyRow, RIGHT(@s, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX('|', @s)) AS Remainder

    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEFT(Remainder, CHARINDEX('|', Remainder) -1) AS MyRow, RIGHT(Remainder, LEN(Remainder) - CHARINDEX('|', Remainder)) AS Remainder
    FROM MyRows
    WHERE CHARINDEX('|', Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Remainder AS MyRow, NULL AS Remainder
    FROM MyRows
    WHERE CHARINDEX('|', Remainder)=0
)
INSERT INTO @tmp (aDate)
SELECT  SUBSTRING(MyRow, 0, 20) as date
FROM MyRows

SELECT *
FROM @tmp
```